Advent of Code 2024 - Day 1 (Common Lisp)
I have recently started learning lisp by reading ANSI Common Lisp, and I thought advent of code would be good for practice. Any feedback on my code for Day 1 would be appreciated.
(require :uiop)

(defparameter *input-file* "01-input")
(defparameter *input-lines* (uiop:read-file-lines *input-file*))

(defun solve ()
  (multiple-value-bind (xs ys) (parse-input-lines *input-lines*)
    (format t "Part 1: ~a~%" (part-1 xs ys))
    (format t "Part 2: ~a~%" (part-2 xs ys))))

(defun parse-input-lines (lines)
  (let (xs ys)
    (loop
      for line in lines
      do (with-input-from-string (s line)
           (push (read s) xs)
           (push (read s) ys)))
    (values (sort xs #'<) (sort ys #'<))))

(defun part-1 (xs ys)
  (reduce #'+ (mapcar (lambda (x y) (abs (- x y))) xs ys)))

(defun part-2 (xs ys)
  (let ((counts (make-hash-table)))
    (loop for y in ys
          do (setf (gethash y counts) (1+ (or (gethash y counts) 0))))
    (loop for x in xs
          sum (* x (or (gethash x counts) 0)) into similarity-score
          finally (return similarity-score))))


Welcome to Code Review! The [tag:programming-challenge] has been added since the code is a solution to a challenge on Advent of Code. Per the excerpt of that tag: "Always include a sufficient description of the problem to be solved - while a link to the challenge is welcome, the review request needs to be complete when the challenge site is unavailable". Can you please [edit] the post to have sufficient details?

Assigning a global to *input-file*, with earmuffs, looks great. But the *input-lines* global feels unnatural. Prefer to just leave it as an anonymous expression within that multiple-value-bind.

Background: Input data is a series of lines, where each line has two integers separated by multiple spaces.
(loop
  for line in lines
  do (with-input-from-string (s line)
       (push (read s) xs)
       (push (read s) ys)))

Not an issue if you're just using the problem's input, but read on untrusted input data can cause arbitrary code execution via reader macros. Safer to disable them (And ensure other sane defaults) with
(uiop:with-safe-io-syntax ()
  (loop
    for line in lines
    do (with-input-from-string (s line)
         (push (read s) xs)
         (push (read s) ys))))

I'd take advantage of loop's collect ... into ... form and parse-integer, though, and skip string streams and read completely:
(defun parse-input-lines (lines)
  (loop
    for line in lines
    for first-space = (position #\Space line)
    collect (parse-integer line :end first-space) into xs
    collect (parse-integer line :start first-space) into ys
    finally (return (values (sort xs #'<) (sort ys #'<)))))

(Well, my actual Common Lisp solution for this problem used cl-ppcre regular expressions to parse the lines.)

(loop for y in ys
  do (setf (gethash y counts) (1+ (or (gethash y counts) 0))))

gethash takes an optional third argument that's used as the default value if the given key isn't present in the hash table, so this could be simplified to
(loop for y in ys
  do (setf (gethash y counts) (1+ (gethash y counts 0))))

but it's even better using incf:
(loop for y in ys
  do (incf (gethash y counts 0)))

